# Multithreaded PictureBox controls rendering

Tags: c#, winforms

So, the subject is describes my question itself but I'll add some notices here. I have around 20 `PictureBox` controls and when the form appears it takes like 0,5 second to load them all. I tried to attach `nvapi.dll` to enable HW rendering, but it looks like that the problem is in something else. So basically I need to render 20 images in multithreaded mode so it'll be faster.

Comment: You only have one UI thread. Are you sure the "rendering" is the bottleneck?

Comment: Not quite sure. Is there a way of creating extra UI thread for PictureBox controls especially?

Comment: Use one picturebox and the use gdi+ to draw the 20 pictures on the picturebox's background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`LoadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww2xzydc(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `PictureBox` to load your images asynchronously:

```
this.pictureBox1.LoadAsync(imagePath);
```

> A call to the `LoadAsync` method sets the
>   [`ImageLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   property to the value of url. Besides calling the `LoadAsync` method,
>   you must set the
>   [`WaitOnLoad`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.waitonload(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `false` (default value) to load an image asynchronously.

Comment: I'm already using it. With `WaitOnLoad` set to `true` too. Sorry, but I forgot to mention that.

Comment: [`WaitOnLoad`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.waitonload(v=vs.110).aspx) should be set to `false`

Comment: Ok, well it looks like that it only loads slow when the `BackgroundImage` is set to some image. I'm using `1024x768` texture with `BackgroundImageLayout` set to `Tile`.

Comment: It changed nothing of setting it to `false`.

Comment: Setting the `WaitOnLoad` property to `true` means the image is loaded synchronously. This causes the user interface to be blocked from other input until the image is loaded. When `WaitOnLoad` is `false` (the default) and the `LoadAsync` method is used to load the image, the `InitialImage` image is displayed when the specified image is loaded, and the user can interact with the interface during the load process.

Comment: The post answer your question about to load the image asynchronously in a different thread. If your performance issue is related to your background image, you can use `Task.Run` and load background image in a separate thread.

Comment: Okay, I'll try loading a background image in a separate thread or either in another `PictureBox` control with `LoadAsync`.

Comment: Okay, so using `Task.Run` ain't gave any results. I'm using the following code: `var bgtask = Task.Run(() => { this.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("./assets/background.bmp"); }); bgtask.Wait();`. Still have no clue why is this happens, maybe I should give a try to [this solution](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?459921-RESOLVED-Background-image-in-form-causing-delay-in-loading-controls&p=1755281#post1755281).

Comment: You should not call `bgtask.Wait();` it makes your form wait until the task completes.

Comment: winforms uses Single Apartment Treads... you can't use multiple threads with the UI message pump.  Use GDI+ with the repaint to draw you pictures on the background or use WPF instead.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that you cannot multi-thread rendering images to picturebox controls, however;

(1) you mention loading 20 1024x768 images - your user cannot see all those at once, so is there a way of loading "just in time" instead if "just in case"

(2) you can definitely multi-thread load Images from files, and then use Invoke() on the UI thead to assign the image created in the loading thread to the pictureBox.Image.

Comment: Your facts are postulate and pretty obvious to spot. I knew this all the time, anyways, thanks for the info about `Invoke()`.